# Get value from input in Ionic 4 alert

Tags: javascript, ionic4

As of today the Ionic 4 documentation on [ion-alert](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert) contains an example how to add a text input to an alert, like this:

```
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'name1',
      type: 'text'
    },
```

But I can not find out how to access the value from the `name1` text input, for example in the button handlers.

Do I have to use something like `document.getElementById` or is there a more Ionic/Angular-style way?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

you can have a button that on the close of the alert can handle the data.

```js
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
    inputs: [
    {
        name: 'name1',
        type: 'text'
    }],    
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel',
            cssClass: 'secondary',
            handler: () => {
                console.log('Confirm Cancel');
            }
        }, 
        {
            text: 'Ok',
            handler: (alertData) => { //takes the data 
                console.log(alertData.name1);
            }
        }
    ]
});
await alert.present();
```

Answer (score 11):

Actually this can be shortened to:

```js
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
    header: 'Prompt!',
    inputs: [
        {
            name: 'input1',
            type: 'text',
            placeholder: 'Please enter text'
        }
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel',
            cssClass: 'secondary',
            handler: () => {
                console.log('Confirm Cancel');
            }
        }, 
        {
            text: 'Ok',
            handler: (alertData) => {
                console.log(alertData.input1);
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

While the parameter `alertData` just contains the inputs with their values:

> [image: alertData in console]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the other answers (and to avoid the use of an inline handler), the input values are also available in the result of `onDidDismiss()`:

```
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
    header   : 'Test',
    buttons: ['OK'],
    inputs: [
        {
            placeholder: 'Name',
            name: 'name',
        },
    ],
});

await alert.present();

const result = await alert.onDidDismiss();

console.log(result);
// {data: {name:'${your input value}'}, role: undefined}
```