# How to get String from input box in Ionic? I'm using Ionic framework for making application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, input, inputbox

I'm trying to get value from my alert in Ionic framework application. I made application and when i click the button, alert(prompt) which i can    input string appears. 
Even i type string in the input box and press 'ok' button , i can't do anything.

I wanna get each input box's string data.
What should i do? Base language is typescript.

I'm trying to put WIFI information in input box and want to handle it. For example, if i type "test" and press 'ok', I wanna save it in variable. Help pls. Tnx

```
async presentAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Input wifi information',
      buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Ok',
            handler: (alertData) => {
              this.data = alertData.ssid+","+alertData.pw+","+alertData.email;
              this.wifiName=alertData.ssid;
              this.wifiPassword=alertData.pw;
              this.email=alertData.email;
          }
        }
    ]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOfeP.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the data like this example:

```
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
    inputs: [
    {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'text'
    }],    
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Ok',
            handler: (data) => {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    ]
});
await alert.present();
```

You can check this old version from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540312/get-value-from-input-in-ionic-4-alert).

Comment: You helped me a lot. Tnx dude!

Comment: I appreciate you